# How do I get an adjusted r-squared for an arima function in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, eviews

I am trying to replicate the output from EViews in R. When I run an ARMA model in Eviews, I get this output
[Eviews Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVQFk.jpg)

The coefficients and standard error are basically the same as the ones that I get from the [R output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/025cM.jpg), with miniscule changes.

This is the code that I use for the R output

```
fed2arma<-arima(nonafed2$GrowthRate, order = c(1,0,1))
fed2arma
```

Specifically, I want to get the R-squared and adjusted R-squared from the model, as shows on the eviews output. I tried the suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619994/how-to-extract-r-squared-from-an-arima-model), of using `summary(fed2arma)$r.squared`, but I got NULL as the output.

Thank you, and apologies in advance for any mistakes in question format--first time user.

Comment: I suggest you to use `auto.arima` from the package `forecast`

Comment: Correlated question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/how-can-i-calculate-the-r-squared-of-a-regression-with-arima-errors-using-r/8751#8751